# About font size in web design

Tags: website-design

I like web 2.0 style design - less info, more space, bigger font-size, etc.
But my designer doesn't.

So when we use a web 2.0 design template, she changes the font size of contents into smaller one like web 1.0 style (ex. 13px).
She just uses the layout only.
She says that large texts look dull.

Of course, this is a subjective matter, but I want to know what you guys think about this.

Comment: I'd like to see a sample of what you're calling "web 2.0 design." There is no "web 2.0" style, movement, genre or "look," so you aren't really asking an answerable question.

Comment: There is certainly subjective opinions, but there's also ways to objectively argue for proper typography. However, the specific answer would be based on the specifics of the individual project. This question is simply to vague to answer with any specificity.

Answer (score 13):

At the risk of alienating myself here, there are a few good designers and a few bad designers and a great many that fall into the middle ground of just average. Before we start telling the OP to put up or shut up shouldn't we see some examples? Make a proper judgement call based on evidence?

If - as it sounds - a template is being used and the designer is randomly changing things just to put their 'stamp' on it, the core design work having already been done in the template, then I'd want to know what the original design looks like, and then compare and contrast.

To the OP I'd say, there are no rules, the design works or it doesn't but your designer should be able to justify their decisions with a coherent and well-reasoned argument and, if necessary, cite studies or research to back it up. After all that, if you still don't like the design, then either ask them to change it the way you want - especially if you are paying the bills - or get a new designer, one whose choices you won't question.

Comment: +1 well said - we are not in possession of the full facts here in order to be able to make informed comment, merely generalizations.

Answer (score 10):

You don't design by committee and you certainly don't design by a bunch of random guys over the internet.  Let your designer do her job, or fire her.

Designing is a complex job that requires balancing a lot of different constraints.  Saying that one isolated item is "wrong" makes very little sense.  In my experience (looking on - I'm a software engineer) a designer's job is just made harder by a bunch of people with no taste or context giving their random opinions -  particularly because design is a "soft skill", everyone feels that their opinion is valid.

If this is a really big deal, and you're unhappy with the whole style, because you feel it's old-fashioned, then make that clear and ask for a re-design.  If you still don't get what you want, then look for a new designer, but focusing on one single aspect, like font size, really makes no sense.

Comment: Why should a non-designer tell the designer what to do? That's like a patient telling his doctor how to perform surgery. The site will end up looking like crap when people with no taste tell the designer what to do.

Comment: While true, a bid part of the problem is client/designer communication. Sometimes the problem is simply that they are a bad designer and/or they have a bad client, but usually it's a communication issue. The designer needs to likely ask better questions to get better direction out of the client.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best things you can do in working with a designer is to provide examples of sites you think have really strong designs to your designer, and explain what you like about them. Often the greatest challenge is just getting on the same page about what you think is strong in any given design, and speaking the same language about it.

For starters, browse some CSS galleries the feature nothing but great sites. Pick out some of the top sites you like, share them with your designer, and explain what you like about them.

You can just Google "CSS Gallery", or just check these:

http://www.cssdrive.com/

http://www.awwwards.com/

http://www.makebetterwebsites.com/

http://www.cssheroes.com/

Comment: YES, YES, this. I do this all the time. I ask clients "point me to two or three sites you love, and tell me why you love them. point me to a site you hate, and tell me why." This is usually WAY faster and easier than trying to get the client to explain what s/he wants in words.